# Underscore _.intersection() - how to?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(["A", "B"]);
arr.push(["A", "C"]);
arr.push(["C", "D"]);
```

How do I pass this array of arrays to intersect to `_.intersection()`?

As `_.intersection(arr)` will not work...

Comment: I'd expect the OP just wants to splat the arguments to `_.intersection()`, so... `[]` in this case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe `_.intersection.apply(_, arr)`?

Comment: Not sure about underscore specifics, but I'd guess `_.intersection.apply(_, arr)` to be safer (as a general practice, if not in this instance).

Comment: Yes. I wrote `null` under the impression that `_` is really only a container, but putting `_` there is safer. Edited.